# Linear extension operators for smooth functions: from compact sets to compact sets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I'm considering a situation where I have the linear restriction map of Fréchet spaces
$$
   C^\infty(C_1) \to C^\infty(C_2)
$$
where $C_2 \hookrightarrow C_1$ are a pair of compact, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to closed balls, and interiors diffeomorphic to open balls. I believe I can assume that $C_2$ is a manifold with at most codimension 3 corners and $C_2$ with at most codimension 2 corners.

> What I'm interested in is whether this has a (Edit: continuous!) linear section.

The case of $n=1$, restriction along $[a,b] \hookrightarrow [c,d]$, I believe I have the requisite understanding to extract as a corollary from [a theorem of Seeley](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2034761) (use $n=0$ in the result that the restriction $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ has a linear section, using the usual Fréchet topologies -- thanks to Andrew Stacey for pointing this out), but I don't know how one would go about the more general case.

In looking around I find a lot of work by Fefferman on the case of $C^k$ maps, and also a lot of work by people considering general extension problems for inclusions $A \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and *arbitrary* functions $A \to \mathbb{R}$ for all different sorts of subsets $A$, including very diverse examples.

Nothing I've found though seems to be the sort of thing I'd need, but that may be my unfamiliarity with this sort of analysis. Ideally, the necessary result is right under my nose, and it just needs someone to say "oh, that clearly follows from so-and-so's theorem".

Comment: For instance, [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/RMI/678) of Fefferman and Ricci ("Some examples of $C^\infty$ extension by linear operators") considers much more wild subsets than I'm interested in.

Comment: In the case where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are euclidean balls with the same center, I would try applying the one-dimensional result along radii. I wonder if that works.

Comment: Another trivial comment is that the nature of $C_1$ isn't really relevant. If you can extend to a small neighborhood of $C_2$ then you can multiply everything by a function that is $1$ on $C_2$ and smoothly goes to $0$ outside the neighborhood. (No doubt you've already noticed that.)

Comment: @NikWeaver thanks for that second comment, I hadn't already noticed. In my case, $C_2$ is the intersection of $C_1$ with another compact connected set, so $C_1$ and $C_2$ share some boundary, so unfortunately I'm not sure your first comment is going to work without serious manipulation.

Comment: As a further lead, theorem 4.8 in [Tame sequence space representations of spaces of $C^\infty$—functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03322228) by Poppenberg looks promising, but I'd have to unwind the bits about 'normwisely tame (with respect to gradings)'

Comment: Jochen Wengenroth seems to be our resident expert on this sort of thing, see his answer to [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60230/are-extensions-of-nuclear-fr%C3%A9chet-spaces-nuclear). If he doesn't see this question you could try asking him directly.

Comment: I'm sure I missed something. It suffices to have a continuous linear extension operator $\mathcal{E}: C^\infty(C_2) \rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, because you can then just restrict to $C_1$. Does the extension operator constructed in Stein's book "Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions" not suffice?

Comment: @DeaneYang that sounds good! I'm completely unfamiliar with the literature, and I've only been digging through papers so far. Any more specific a reference (eg chapter/verse?)

Comment: @NikWeaver I think I may even have a paper copy of that Springer LNM he references!

Comment: @DeaneYang Ah, I see: Chapter VI.

Comment: It's Theorem 5 in section VI.3 (page 181). It works on Lipschitz domains, which I believe includes your case.

Comment: David, you're welcome. I'm happy that I didn't actually misunderstand the question. Sorry if I acted like everybody should know about Stein's theorem. I found it very useful myself years ago and was very lucky to stumble onto it,

Comment: @DeaneYang now I've looked at it and, sadly, that's a Banach space (i.e. Sobolev class) result! Maybe the technique works for my case, but the reason I'm asking here is my functionalanalysis-fu is not up to scratch for this result.

Comment: David, it constructs a single extension operator that works for all Sobolev spaces simultaneously. That implies that it is a continuous operator between the respective $C^\infty$ spaces with respect to the Frechet topology.

Comment: @DeaneYang ok, now I have educated myself about the literature surrounding the problem, and I agree I was hasty about brushing off your comment. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there are several candidates for the definition of $C^\infty(K)$:
One is the space $\lbrace f|_K: f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\rbrace$ of all restrictions (endowed with the quotient topology), another is the intersection  $\bigcap\limits_{k\in\mathbb N_0} \lbrace f|_K: f\in C^k(\mathbb R^n)\rbrace$ (which is equal to the former for $n=1$ due to Merrien but different in general — an elementary example is in
*Wieslaw Pawlucki*, [**On the algebra of functions $\scr C^k$-extendable for each $k$ finite**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-04-07756-1), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **133** (2005), no. 2, 481–484), and finally the probably best understood definition is that of Whitney jets, i.e. families $(f^{(\alpha)})_{\alpha \in \mathbb N_0^d}$ of continuous functions which satisfy the correct Taylor approximations on $K$ as if $f^{(\alpha)}=\partial^{\alpha} f$ for some $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.

If $K$ is the closure of its interior the definitions coincide and you should consult the literature about extension of Whitney jets. The article 
*Leonhard Frerick*, [**Extension operators for spaces of infinite differentiable Whitney jets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/CRELLE.2007.005), *J. Reine Angew. Math.* **602** (2007), 123–154, contains a lot of information. As mentioned by Deane Yang. Lipschitz boundary is enough for having a continuous linear extension operator (this is due to E.M. Stein). However, a sharp cusp like $K=\lbrace (x,y)\in [0,1]^2: y\le \exp(-1/x)\rbrace$ does not have such an extension.
For general $K$ and the space of all restrictions, the question is wide open, besides the examples of Fefferman and Ricci mentioned by David Roberts there are some results of *Dietmar Vogt*, [**Restriction spaces of $A^\infty$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/RMI/769), *Rev. Mat. Iberoam.* **30** (2014), no. 1, 65–78.

Comment: I've always wondered whether Stein was the first to do this for a domain with smooth boundary or whether his Lipschitz boundary theorem was the first to do this case.

Comment: I am hoping my case is the one where the smaller set is the closure of its interior, and these closed sets arise from rather flexible geometric considerations, so they can be tweaked a little to avoid cusps.

Comment: @DeaneYang Extensions from intervals were done by Mityagin in 1961. In 1964 Seeley constructed extension operators for half spaces. Although he did not write it explicitly, this covers more or less the case of smooth boundaries. Stein's result for Lipschitz boundaries is from 1970.